# Creating a new instance from within CFC

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

Now this would seem to be something very straight forward, but seemingly not so in ColdFusion. I need to create an instance of a CFC from within itself as in `var a = new this()` but this obviously does not work. The CFC name can't be used as it is a base that will be extended so I am attempting a hack around the issue with the following:

```
component {
    public function subQuery (required string table) {

        var classPath = getMetaData(this).fullname;
        return createObject("component", classPath).init(table, this.dsn);

    }
}
```

This would be acceptable but the class path returned from `getMetaData(this).fullname` is incorrect. The CFC is within a folder named with a hypen as in `my-folder` and the returned path looks like `my.-folder.myCFC` with a period inserted before the hyphen. Obviously I could manipulate this string with a Regex but that is just not a road I want to go down.

Hoping someone has a cleaner approach, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it without any context on the object name in theory, as it will be being executed from within itself and it should check its current directory.

The following should therefore do the job you need

```
var classPath = ListLast(getMetaData(this).fullname,'.');
return createObject("component", classPath).init(table, this.dsn);
```

This way it doesn't matter what the directory names are, and it will work on any objects that extend that one regardless of directory structure, or for a complete example

```
public function cloneMe() {
    return CreateObject('component', ListLast(getMetaData(this).fullname,'.')).init(argumentCollection=arguments);
}
```

This way any arguments passed in will be passed through into the init.  I.e. an extending CFC may redefine the method as the following (if you want errors when the init arguments aren't supplied)

```
public function cloneMe(required string table) {
    return super.cloneMe(table=arguments.table,dsn=this.dsn);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that I had missed some built in method for doing this in the docs but perhaps not. While this still seems like a horrible hack I guess I don't have any better option. Thanks for your help Simon.

Comment: I've had similar issues when trying to invoke child objects, and ultimately the relative path addressed them as otherwise, as you identified, was having to fall back onto regex or mappings - both of which are not ideal / hindered portability/extendability